# Erro java.lang.NullPointerException ao tentar popular Spinner

Tags: android, sqlite

Dentro da OnCreate:

```
  spnMateriasID = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnMateria);


        try{

            atividadeModel = new AtividadeModel(this);
            atividadeModel.getWritableDatabase();

            materiaModel = new MateriaModel(this);
            materiaModel.getWritableDatabase();

            adapterMateria = buscaMaterias(this);

        } catch(SQLException ex){
            Toast.makeText(this, ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


        spnMateriasID.setAdapter(adapterMateria);




     public ArrayAdapter<String> buscaMaterias(Context context){
        ArrayAdapter<String> materias = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);

        Cursor dados = conn.query("materias",null, null, null, null, null, null);

        if(dados.getCount() > 0){
            dados.moveToFirst();

            while(dados.moveToNext()){
                materias.add(dados.getString(1));
            }

        }

        return materias;
    }
```

Comment: Felipe coloca mais detalhes do problema na pergunta. Em qual linha exatamente ocorre o erro?

Comment: Esse é o erro gerado ao tentar buscar os dados e popular o ArrayAdapter;
Problema é que toda vez que tento abrir a conexão da algum erro.

Comment: Onde esta definida a variável `conn`? Parece que falta mais códigos ai, coloca a pilha de erro tbm.

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                              at com.example.felipe.tutor.Adicionaatividade.buscaMaterias(Adicionaatividade.java:120)
                                                                              at com.example.felipe.tutor.Adicionaatividade.onCreate(Adicionaatividade.java:61)
                                                                              at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)

Não Consegui por tudo

Comment: Acima do OnCreate tenho declarada:
private SQLiteDatabase conn;

Comment: Você inicializou a variável `conn`? Atribui uma instancia a ela?

Comment: Nossa muita falta de atenção. Iniciei a SQLiteDataBase conn e funcionou,

Muito obrigado mesmo por me ajudar.